# Returning a void pointer as thread return

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

This is a stripped example from [apue](http://www.apuebook.com/apue3e.html)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void err_exit(const char* text){
    char buf[200];
    sprintf(buf, text);
    perror(buf);
    abort();
}

void * thr_fn1(void *arg)
{
    printf("thread 1 returning \n");
    return ((void *)1);
    //This is returning the pointer to 1.
    //Is this address somewhat special?
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int         err;
    pthread_t   tid1;
    void        *tret;

    err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thr_fn1, NULL);
    if (err != 0) {
        err_exit("can't create thread 1");
    }

    err = pthread_join(tid1, &tret);
    if (err != 0) {
        err_exit("can't join with thread 1");
    }

    printf("Return of thread 1 %ld\n", (long)tret);
    return 0;
}
```

Two things are unclear to me in this example.

I'm interpreting `return ((void *)1);` as `return a void pointer pointing to address 1`. Why is this ok? Choosing an arbitrary memory location like that and perceiving it as an exit status?

`printf("Return of thread 1 %ld\n", (long)tret);` the returned `((void *)1)`, now `tret` is cast to long through which we're extending it to `long` from `char`. Why is there enough information supplied in this source code so that we can safely consume a `"long number of memory from address 1"` ?

Comment: Having a pointer to some non-allocated memory area is allright as long as you do not try to de-reference it, which is not done in this example. While a pointer would normally be used as, well transporting some address around, it is used in this case to transport a value. Not nice, but works.

Comment: @tofro So this is a pattern for passing an integer value without consuming memory?

Comment: It does rely on the assumption that the compiler will be able to convert an integer value of "1" to a `(void*)` and back without losing any bits (that should be allright for small values and "works" for basically all current mainstream systems - It is *not guaranteed* by the standard for all possible values). I currently don't know of any system where it wouldn't work. The *correct* (by the book) way is still to allocate some memory for the return value, put that value there and return a pointer to it *as a pointer*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting an integer to a void pointer is implementation defined:

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 5. An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>      result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>      entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

(In the case of trap representation the behavior is undefined.)

Again casting a pointer to an integer is also implementation defined. The type of `1` before being cast to `void*` was actually `int` not `char`, but that doesn't matter anymore as the type of the object is `void*` and it is being converted to `long`.

> 6. Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>      result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>      the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>      type.

The correct way to return is to return a pointer to an object with a static or allocated storage duration. Since you are returning error codes, we can make an assumption that there are a limited amount of them so a const static object would work:

```
void* thr_fn1(void* arg)
{
    printf("thread 1 returning \n");
    static const long ok_return = 1;
    return (void*)&ok_return;
}
```

Printing the object is different since we have a valid pointer to a long object:

```
printf("Return of thread 1 %ld\n", *(const long*)tret);
```

Comment: I find your code much more understandable than the example I posted. I'm looking for a motivation for this kind of example and so far the only assumption I have currently is that it the example approach doesn't spend memory for passing the error code.

Comment: @Alan You really shouldn't worry about sizeof(long) extra bits in the binary.

Comment: I agree :) Am just trying to find if I'm missing a concept here given that this was presented to me as the bible of Unix programing.

Comment: @Alan You can certainly heed their advice if you plan to code for UNIX only.

Comment: Returning the address of `static const long ok_return = 1;` or any similar approach works if `thr_fn1()` has only one instantiation at any time.  If multiple threads are running `thr_fn1()` simultaneously, the return values will share the same static variable.  In that case, to be strictly-conforming C, you'd have to dynamically allocate memory an integer-type variable, return a pointer to it, and then free the memory after collecting the result.

Comment: @AndrewHenle They will share the same static variable, and? My approach is strictly conforming. The object is defined with const and will only be read. (It is no different than a const variable defined in file scope.)

Comment: @2501 `They will share the same static variable, and?` Since they all share the same variable, they'll either all corrupt each others return value, or they'll all return the same value and thus actually return zero information, making the return value useless.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  That is nonsense and not correct. Please learn about the static keyword.

Comment: @2501 *That is nonsense and not correct. Please learn about the static keyword.*  Really? Are you actually claiming you don't understand both (1) how multiple threads sharing a single static value prevents accurate return values from all those threads, and (2) how always returning the same value provides exactly the same lack of actual information as a `void` return of nothing at all does?  You do realize that always returning the same value is exactly the same as a dead clock that you know is stuck at 2 o'clock?  And you're telling me I don't understand `static`??!?!

Comment: @AndrewHenle My intention is to provide criticism. I hope you are capable of accepting it like an adult mind would. Judging from your last two comments, I would have to say, if you asked me, and you did, that you don't know C very well. I have a hunch you think I'm trying to offend you or something like that. Nothing could be further from the truth. I really just want to help you.  My suggestion to you is to learn C, from the ground up, starting with passing and returning values. Peace out!